# Why when I try to run this xml file I get an error, is the same on all webpages use

Tags: xml

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Location: file:///C:/Users/HectorM/Documents/CMIS%20170%20Week%202.xml

Line Number 8, Column 1:
<st:collegeStudent xmlns:st="http://www.dontknowmuch.com/namespace" >
^
```

Please need suggestions or correction for this error if not problem to outstanding individuals as yourselves, thanks.

Comment: With a single line, its hard to analyse. Post bit more xml snippet.

Answer (score 1):

"Junk after document element" pointing at the start of an element probably means that you have more than one top-level element in your file. That isn't a well-formed Document, and parsers will correctly complain about it. Fix the file to have a single top-level element, or if you absolutely can't do so construct a "wrapper" document which refers to this file as an External Parsed Entity and expands that entity within a top-level element it supplies.